# If $\int f = 0$ and $\int fg =0$ for $g \geq 0$ then $f=0$ a.e.?

Tags: integration, functions

Here, all integrals are over $[0,T]$. Suppose $\int f = 0$ and $\int fg = 0$ for some $g \geq 0$. Is it true that this implies $f=0$ a.e. in $[0,T]$?

I don't think it is true but maybe I am missing a  mean value type theorem?

Comment: No, take $g=0$ and $f$ arbitrary with vanishing integral.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No:
$$
f(x) = \begin{cases} 1 : x \in [0, T/2] \\ -1 : x \in (T/2, T] \end{cases} \\
g(x) = 1
$$

Answer (score 0):

The answer is no. Take $f(x)=\sin(2\pi x/T)$ and $g(x)\equiv 1$. Then we have 
$$\int_0^Tf(x)dx=\int_0^Tf(x)g(x)dx=\int_0^T\sin(2\pi x/T)dx=-\frac{T}{2\pi}\cos(2\pi x/T)\Big|_0^T=0.$$